# Changing Zone in Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure

I have a AvailabilityZone set to my deployed VMSS, i would like to know how can i add and change AvailabilityZone to my current vmss but i cant find any option to do so.
I would really appreciate any inputs

Change the Availability Zone Sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add an existing VM to an availability set after it's created. VMs must be created within the availability set to make sure they're correctly distributed across the hardware. A VM can only be added to an availability set when it is created. To change the availability set, you need to delete and then recreate the virtual machine.

Please refer to the below documents for more information :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-availability-sets
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/change-availability-set